# javascript regular expression for atleast one number and one uppercase letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

what would be the regular expression to check if a given string contains atleast one number and one uppercase letter?
Thanks in advance

I am doing like this

```
function validate_pass{
var var_password = document.getElementById("npassword").value;
else if (!(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).+$/).test(var_password))){
    msg = "Password should contain atleast.";

    showErrorMsgPassword(msg);
    $('#npassword').val('');
    $('#cpassword').val('');
    return false;
  }

else return true;
```

Comment: like `/[0-9]+[A-Z]+/` or `/[0-9]+[A-Z]/`?

Comment: You need to provide more info, such as examples of what you want to match and what you want to *not* match. You've given nothing here that makes your question possible to answer. Please edit to improve it so people can help you. Thanks. :)

Comment: the digit  & uppercase can appear anywhere is the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this, and I'm fairly certain there is a more efficient way than this. You will need to use positive lookaheads, but there should be a way to remove the wildcards from within them:

This regex (`/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*$/`) will return the entire password if it matches the criteria.

`('a3sdasFf').match(/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*$/);`

Answer (score 3):

If the desire is to test a string to see if it has a least one digit and at least one uppercase letter in any order and with any other characters allowed too, then this will work:

```
var str = "abc32Qdef";
var re = /[A-Z].*\d|\d.*[A-Z]/;
var good = re.test(str);​
```

Working demo with a bunch of test cases here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gYEmC/

Comment: You could use `.test` method of the Regex object.

Comment: @xdazz - I switched to `.test()`.

Answer (score 0):

Like below:

```
/(\d.*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*\d)/
```

To test a string matched or not:

```
var str = "abc32dQef";
var is_matched = /(\d.*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*\d)/.test(str);
```

Comment: @mshsayem Have you tried `/(\d.*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*\d)/.test("abc32dQef")`? Note: if you want to match the ending, you should use `$`.