# Regular Expression That Contains At Least One Of Each

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to capitalize "words" that have at least one number, letter, and special character such as a period or dash.

Things like: `3370.01b`, `6510.01.b`, `m-5510.30`, and `drm-2013-c-004914`.

I don't want it to match things like: `hello`, `sk8`, and `mixed-up`

I'm trying to use lookaheads, [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004205/javascript-regular-expression-for-atleast-one-number-and-one-uppercase-letter), but I can't get it to match anything.

```
$output = preg_replace_callback('/\b(?=.*[0-9]+)(?=.*[a-z]+)(?=.*[\.-]+)\b/i', function($matches){return strtoupper($matches[0]);}, $input);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the strings you want,

```
(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*\d)[a-z\d]+(?:[.-][a-z\d]+)+
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?=\S*[a-z])` - This look ahead ensures that there is at least an alphabet character in the incoming word
- `(?=\S*\d)` - This look ahead ensures that there is at least a digit in the incoming word
- `[a-z\d]+(?:[.-][a-z\d]+)+` - This part captures a word contain alphanumeric word containing at least one special character `.` or `-`

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2NPnvg/1)**

Here is the PHP code demo modifying your code,

```
$input = '3370.01b, 6510.01.b, m-5510.30, and drm-2013-c-004914 hello, sk8, and mixed-up';
$output = preg_replace_callback('/(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*\d)[a-z\d]+(?:[.-][a-z\d]+)+/i', function($matches){return strtoupper($matches[0]);}, $input);
echo $output;
```

Prints,

```
3370.01B, 6510.01.B, M-5510.30, and DRM-2013-C-004914 hello, sk8, and mixed-up
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you never captured anything to put into matches...

```
$input = '3370.01b foo';
$output = preg_replace_callback('/(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(\w+(?:[-.]\w+)+)/i', function($matches){return strtoupper($matches[0]);}, $input);

echo $output;
```

Output

```
3370.01B foo
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46cd32ed44cfbc51ac3dd74da86550bf89061ca3)

https://regex101.com/r/syJWMN/1

Comment: Your solution also matches `aaa-ddd` `111-222` strings which according to OP shouldn't match as the word should contain at least a digit and an alphabet within the word. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/syJWMN/2)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression:

https://regex101.com/r/sdmlL8/1

```
(?=.*\d)(.*)([-.])(.*)
```

PHP code:

https://ideone.com/qEBZQc

```
$input = '3370.01b';
$output = preg_replace_callback('/(?=.*\d)(.*)([-.])(.*)/i', function($matches){return strtoupper($matches[0]);}, $input);
```

Comment: As per OP it should not match if the word contains only number and it should also contain an alphabet too.