# Can we define character class inside another character class in regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I want to check following conditions for a string:

1. At least one alphabet in `[a-z]`
2. At least one alphabet should be of Upper Case `[A-Z]`
3. At least 1 number or digit between `[0-9]`.
4. At least 1 character from [ `_` or `@` or `$` ].

One solution is to write regular expression separately for each condition but i do not want to do that.
Any suggestions for this one guies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression That Contains At Least One Of Each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316341/regular-expression-that-contains-at-least-one-of-each)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be a single regex you can use

`(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)`

You can check how it works here https://regex101.com/r/8raurw/1

Comment: (?=.*\W) does not match the listed special characters, (?=.*[_@$]) is needed

Comment: why '.*' is mentioned inside the RE, can't we just write [a-z] or [a-z]+

Comment: Let us add one more condition to the above mentioned conditioned that, length of the string should be atleast 8 characters